# C# Winform Storing and Passing Variables?

Tags: c#, winforms

So for 99% of my learning of C# it has been with console applications, now I'd like to try simple GUI i.e win form apps. But I have no idea on how to get the input from a text box, store it as an int or double and pass it to a method that will just do a simple task like converting it into pounds (lb).
Sorry for such a noob question but how do I do this? I know how to make the method just not how to get input and pass variables from a textbox...

Comment: `var text = textbox1.Text;`. The rest is identical to a Console application.

Comment: [Tutorial 2: Create a Timed Math Quiz](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492172.aspx) Walk through this simple real-life application example and test it step by step

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd give a simple example.
Add two components to your form. 1) Textbox,  2) Button
Then OnClick of the button should read `TextBox1.Text` value as string and do whatever you want with it, I believe you are familiar with parsing and dealing with variables.

Comment: I tried this
https://paste.ofcode.org/BjKhDmjb8E2fHNhtCHD3ZY
But on clicking the button nothing happens, I know I'm doing something simple wrong and will bash my head in when I notice but I can't put my finger on it...

Comment: I think all you need is to show the result on the form. Try adding a third component which is Label, and then `Label1.Text = PoundsToStone(text).ToString();`

Comment: Causes and error on line 35 sadly
https://paste.ofcode.org/HYEtQpAKXxEZe23VsTSqMx
Don't know why I'm finding this hard, says text doesn't exist in this context

Comment: Don't add it in `Label1.Click`, it should be in `Button1.Click` So click function of the button should read the value from textbox, call the function `PoundsToStone` and add the value for `Label1'

Answer (score 0):

A textbox object has an "Text"-Attribute. A simple solution is (without any exception-handling):

```
string tmp = myTextbox.Text;
int val1 = int.Parse(tmp);
double val2 = Double.Parse(tmp);
```